# Can I prevent "Photos" app from loading?

Tags: applications, photos, macos

I really dislike using "photos" app it is simply an un needed app for me because I have minimal HD space and do not need a back-up and do not want a cloud back-up either. I would love it if I could prevent the app from loading altogether.

Comment: Want do you mean by loading? Do you want to delete it? Make it so it won't open at log in?

Comment: no, I just want to prevent photos from opening when I plug in a camera. it seems once you format an SD card the photos app will open like its the first time again.

Answer (score 2):

When you say **loading** you mean `Photos` will open once you connect a device to your mac?

Use the `Image Capture` app to configure what app is loaded for that device. You can turn off loading of `Photos`, too. This setting is on the bottom left, you might hat to click the arrow-up sign to see the app selection box.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I am getting this wrong but it sounds like you want to get rid of the photos app. In [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-useless-apps-pre-installed-on-my-mac), [Tony Van Der Harst](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/30720/tony-van-der-harst) recommends the following:

> Appcleaner is one app that I have used for several years to tidy stuff up. Never had a single issue with deleting Stickies, Notes, Bootcamp Assistant, Audio Midi Setup, RAID, Podcast, etc, etc. Appcleaner preferences should be set up to delete "protected" apps and then will delete the app and all the other files (plists, etc.) that go with it.
>
> Another app, CleanMyMac, does the same, but will also do a more general clearout of caches, etc. Both recommended...

But you do have to keep in mind what [patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix) says:

> I strongly recommend against removing standard applications:
>
> - Most of them need hardly any space at all (the three mentioned in the question need 14 MBytes together)
> - An upcoming OS X version may expect them to be there
> - There is no easy way to get them back once you removed them

If it opens on log in you can change that by right clicking on the app icon when it is on the dock and select 'open at log in':

[image]

Comment: I agree that you do not want to remove this app, thanks for the suggestion.