# How to delete pre-installed apps on macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, applications, bash, catalina

Update:

### Please check the [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/dfetr4/how_to_i_delete_default_apps_in_catalina/) linked by @Phill, verified on 10.15.4

---

I used `csrutil disable` to turn off System Integrity Protection and deleted some unused pre-installed apps before macOS 10.14. Recently, I upgraded to macOS 10.15 Beta (19A487l) and found this way didn't work anymore. My admin account only has **Read-only** access for pre-installed applications.

The `/Applications` in Terminal is actually `/System/Volumes/USER-Data/Applications`.

```bsh
➜  ~ ls /Applications       
Alfred 4.app           Safari.app             Utilities
Google Chrome.app      ShadowsocksX-NG.app    Visual Studio Code.app
```

I don't have write access to `/System/Applications`.

```bsh
➜  ~ sudo rm -rf /System/Applications/Stickies.app
...
rm: /System/Applications/Stickies.app: Read-only file system
```

I also cannot change the privilege from `Finder -> /System/Applications/Stickies.app -> Get Info -> Sharing & Permissions`, it says:

> The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.

I've read [Is it possible to delete the "useless" apps pre-installed on my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-useless-apps-pre-installed-on-my-mac) and `chflags` didn't work either because of **Read-only**.

How can I access to the "real" `system` account or is there the other way to delete or hide those applications?

Thank you.

[image: App Info]

Comment: where is the duplicated question/answer?

Comment: The arrival of Catalina (10.15) made all previous answer obsolete, so I think this is a valid question and not a duplicate. If I'm mistaken, which is not impossible of course, then I would like to find the duplicate question/answer as well (couldn't find it at SE).

Comment: I'm astounded this question is closed. I have this exact problem, and while the linked question is related, it is not at all helpful for someone who just wants an answer! I found a solution in a reddit thread. When you log back in (after disabling SIP) you need to `sudo mount uw /` then you can delete the apps (at least you can using AppCleaner). Thread link: https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/dfetr4/how_to_i_delete_default_apps_in_catalina/

Comment: That should be `sudo mount -uw /`

Comment: @Phill Awesome! It works on 10.15.4