# Remove preinstalled apps on Big Sur MacBook Pro M1

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur, parental-controls

Sorry for my English, I'm French and [I've given up trying to remove preinstalled apps like Tv.app and FaceTime. app.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-useless-apps-pre-installed-on-my-mac)

I have  tried a lot (even with SIP disabled) but nothing works. I'm kind very desperate since I’m not sure how I would set up screen time to limit my children’s usage of the Pre-installed apps.

The reason why I need to do so, is that my kid waste time in stead of studying. Is there a guide how to set this up?

Comment: A newer question has provided more details so we will close this forward instead of reverse for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest path forward would be to make your account the administrator and grant each child their own managed AppleID and their own sign in and force them to abide by Screen Time limits.

You are correct that uninstalling the core parts of the system is [a bit like the task of sysiphus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus).

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210387 (Guide on app restrictions)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201084 (Guide on Family accounts)

You likely won’t even need to resort to stricter measures like a free / hosted MDM like https://app.jamfnow.com/devices

I have not had success [messing with the Sealed System Volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414186/5472) (SSV) in Big Sur, but people are starting to document how this works publicly.